# adding in a QTextEdit widget as the central widget makes main window not pop up, and showMaximize causes computer crash?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt

I have the following skeleton code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QMainWindow, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Editor(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.initUI()

    # --------------------------------------

    def initMenubar(self):

      menubar = self.menuBar()

      fileMenuBtn = menubar.addMenu("File")
      editMenuBtn = menubar.addMenu("Edit")
      viewMenuBtn = menubar.addMenu("View")

    # --------------------------------------    
    def initToolbars(self):

      self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Options")
      # Makes the next toolbar appear underneath this one
      self.addToolBarBreak()
      self.formatbar = self.addToolBar("Format")        

    # --------------------------------------        
    def initUI(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('Monospace', 10))

        self.setToolTip('<b>Proofor</b> main window')

        #self.text = QTextEdit(self)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.text)


        # Initialize a statusbar for the window
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()

        self.initToolbars()
        self.initMenubar()

        self.setWindowTitle('Proofor - proof editor')
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('dots.png'))

        #self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)

# ================================================

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Editor()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If run this code as is (`python editor.py`), then everything works okay. However, if I un-comment the lines that add a `QTextEdit` widget, in `initUI`, I get the following warnings appearing:

```
(python:1949): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (/Editor) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
```

The window that would otherwise pop-up doesn't, but I can still close up the application. Instead, if in `main` I have `main.showMaximized()` rather than `main.show()`, I cause my computer to crash. This does not happen if I don't have a `QTextEdit` widget set as the central widget, since otherwise, a normal, maximized window appears.

Any ideas regarding what's happening?

---

**edit for posterity:** issue was occurring within my Anaconda Python distribution, I had installed pyqt5 which was conflicting with the native pyqt4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under python 3.4, pyqt5, ubuntu 14.04 lts your code works well.
It seems to be a problem of the default style on your installation

try to change the style by running your code with e.g.

```
python editor.py -style windows
```

see [Qt-Docs QStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#details)

you can find the available styles by

```
print(QStyleFactory.keys())
```

after importing QStyleFactory from QtWidgets

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have two questions for you: 1) [do you get the following warnings when running the code](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249013/getting-gtk-warning-gmodule-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-gtk-2-0-2-10-0-immod) and 2) why does your answer work (I tried it, and it does work -- I am on Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: Worth noting that out of the styles I have available (windows, fusion, and gtk+), it is the gtk+ one that causes my computer to completely crash!

Comment: i had the error message with my own app under ubuntu 13.xx and found the solution (setting another style) by duckduckgo. since ubuntu 14.04 my app runs without this error. your code doesn't  show any error message even if i run it with -style gtk+